# reStructuredText citations page number support

Tags: restructuredtext, citations

Does reStructuredText support page numbers in its citations somehow? I've only seen plain labels like `[Test10]_` in examples so far, but not for example `[Test10 p. 20]_`.

I think this is quite important for scientific papers. You don't want to force a reader, who checks a source to read a whole book to find what you're referring to. Or even a whole paper for that matter. So it seems to me like there should be support for it, but I could not find it so far.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what I was looking for :-)

You could try something like this:

```
.. footer:: page ###Page###
```

It also works with the directive `.. header::`

See :

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/17/an-intro-to-rst2pdf-changing-restructured-text-into-pdfs-with-python/
- https://pythonhosted.org/linkdown/doc/rst/cheatsheet.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe I've found a better way for now. By now I wrote my own little parsers + converters, which convert citations, which it can find in a bib file to `raw-latex` citations (as rst text role) and document internal links into also `raw-latex` text role hyperreferences. My build process for the PDF now looks like this: `rst --parser-citations--> rst --parser-internal-links--> rst --pandoc+template--> latex --latexmk--> very neat PDF` with all features. You can get the parsers form my GitHub repos: https://github.com/ZelphirKaltstahl?tab=repositories (search for `rst`)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own parsers and converters for `rst`, which convert citations and internal links to `raw-latex` citations and hyperrefs. You can find the code in my [GitHub repos](https://github.com/ZelphirKaltstahl?tab=repositories). My build process for a PDF from rst now looks like this:

1. convert citations using my own [parser](https://github.com/ZelphirKaltstahl/rst-citations-to-raw-latex)
2. convert internal links using my own [parser](https://github.com/ZelphirKaltstahl/rst-internal-links-to-raw-latex)
3. use `pandoc` to convert to latex
4. use `latexmk` to compile a pdf

I have a bash script for running these steps in sequence, but it is specific to my directory structure.

Hope it will be helpful for people. Maybe some day Pandoc will take care of all of this (I hope so.)